# How to iterate a ArrayList inside a HashMap Android

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I created a `HashMap` something like this

```
hashDataChild = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, List<String>>
```

what i want to do is to iterate the `ArrayList` which is inside my `HashMap`

basically I want to achieve something like this

```
ArrayList<String> arrayOfString;

for (Integer i = 0; i<=header_data.size(); i++){
     hashDataChild.put(arrayOfString.get(i), child);
}
```

So whenever it loops, each header, a child will be displayed.

I'm trying to create a expandable listview with this. How can i achieve something like this?

Is it necessary to put my `HashMap` inside a ArrayList which would be like this

```
ArrayList<HashMap<ArrayList<String>, List<String>>>
```

Because I look for some example and I found this code but there is no explanation on what and how it do.

```
`List<String>` for my second argument in my HashMap i created this

child = new ArrayList<String>();

    child.add("Child 1");
    child.add("Child 2");
    child.add("Child 3");
```

I used `ArrayList<String>` as the first argument to be my header which its data are from multiple columns from the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
   import java.util.Iterator;
   import java.util.Map;
   import java.util.Map.Entry;

hashDataChild = new HashMap<ArrayList<String>, List<String>>


Iterator<Entry<ArrayList<String>, ArrayList<String>>> it=map.entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){

 Map.Entry<ArrayList<String>, List<String>>
pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();

 ArrayList<String> arraylist=pair.getKey();

 //iterate.... here iterate logic
List<String> list=pair.getValue();
}
```

Comment: at the Iterator I'm having an error that says "Wrong number of type argument: 2, required 1"

Comment: it only displays
Error:(242, 17) error: wrong number of type arguments; required 1

Comment: there was a mistake. sorry I dont have any IDE.

Comment: it says here that it cannot resolve symbol Entry so i tried changing it to Map.Entry and also cannot resolve symbol map. Is map is equivalent to hashDataChild?

Comment: Import these packages.                import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82901/discussion-between-codeprocessor-and-kairi-san).

Comment: I replied on the discussion @CodeProcessor